# What is the best way to store product description/details in a database table. PHP mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Let's say we have a product with these descriptions (displayed like so, one per line):

Description 1

Description 2

Description 3

Description 4

.

.

Description N

what is the best way to store these product descriptions in a database table so they can be displayed in a "description" Tab of a dynamic product page.

I would like to avoid creating N different table columns, one for each description.

Thank you for your suggestions

Comment: Using a join table and store your descriptions in another table?

Answer (score 1):

Create another relation table.

Product table:

```
id
name
serial
....
```

Description table:

```
id
product_id
description
order / could be 1,2,3,n/
```

And then you can:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM descriptions"
    . " WHERE product_id  = " . $productId . ""
    . " ORDER BY `order`";
```

Read more about it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

**EDIT**

I've added on order column, because i'ev assume, you want to display the description in correct order. If you do not use this `order` field, you can't be sure, when you selecting descriptions for 1 product, then which order do you get back them.

```
id | product_id | description | order
1    1            This is the   1
                  first desc 

2    1            This is the   3
                  3rd

3    1            This is the   2
                  2nd
```

so you have the freedom to add description in any order, but keep their proper orders. The `order` field name can be any other name eg: `desc_order`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't get the "order/could be 1,2,3,n/" part. Could you explain it further?

Answer (score 0):

If you have n amount of descriptions per product I suggest you create a new table which has a relation to the product table. Now you can create one to many (or many to many with one composite table added) relationship and do not have to worry about how many different descriptions you get.

After that you can get all the descriptions for the product with JOIN clause

Comment: Depending on are you creating relational DB I suggest that you check out normal forms and how "one to many" and "many to many" are properly implemented

Answer (score 0):

If you like to separate each description, then you may use an array, then json_encode() the array.

```
<?php
   $text = [
      [0] => 'desc 1',
      [1] => 'desc 2',
      ...
   ];
   $json_text = json_encode($text);
   // save $json_text to the field.

   // to extract the from table
   $text = json_decode($text);
   for($text as $t) {
     echo $t; //the descs.
   }
```

You could also use serialize().

This is just an option, then use a relative table, but for a faster fetching of data, you may use this approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you have many type of a product and they have special description then you can use line item concept in your design,
see this [example](http://help.filemaker.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3246/~/relational-database-design-101-(part-3-of-3))

For example you can have two table as following :

Producttbl (**productID**, productName, totalnumber , baseprice)

Productitemtbl (itemid, ***productid*** , description, price , discount)

If you have a shop, this is one of the efficient method for storing your products and their descriptions!